# android development on netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

I'm trying to develop on android's platform. I'm working with netbeans and using this tutorial: **[Introducing Android Development with NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans)**. I seem to have everything installed properly, and have no trouble creating android projects, but when I try to debug I get several error messages like,

```
W/ResourceType( 3449): Bad string block: string #0 extends to 1029, past end at 60
```

followed by several which look like

```
AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'label' in package 'android'
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this or how I could fix it?

Comment: If anyone has any information about why I would get a "An error occurred while installing the items
  session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.cvs 1.0.400.v201002111343, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
  The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.400.v201002111343 was not found."    error, when trying to install the plugin, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Could you paste your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

the Android SDK was designed to work with Eclipse, so i would recommend you switch. I realise this is not the answer you were looking for, but in the long run you will save time unless someone continues the nbandroid project (which was updated 1 year ago). also you will receive support here quicker.

Edit: Netbeans is being maintained as a dev platform for Android (through the nbAndroid plugin).

Comment: No, the Android SDK was not designed to work with Eclipse. It was designed to work with any IDE (or even without one).

I'm using Netbeans for Android dev every day and its working great. 
Only real thing missing is the visual XML layout editor, which is great for beginners and mockups but becomes less relevant in later stages

Comment: @Jacob Nordfalk: whatever. in any case, it's the IDE that is recommended and most often referred to by the Android dev team in the official docs.

Comment: nbAndroid appears to be staying current now.  They've even got info up for NetBeans 7.2 (currently in beta).